# IE consistently prints blank pages for website, and not for others

Tags: internet-explorer, printing

We have an internal website that when we try to print from it with Internet Explorer all pages except the first and last print blank (except for the IE header/footer information with the URL and date/time info which shows up fine), we tried on IE6/7/8 and they all acted the same way.  No matter what page on the site we print from, unless the printed form will fit on a single page, this happens.  On the last page (whether the print job is 2 pages or 20 pages long) we get a big gap/margin at the top of the last page followed by a little bit of the information from the last page.

On all other websites I've tested apart from this one, including other internal websites, printing from IE does not have any issues.

Now the kicker... I went to go "fix" the issue in our dev region, assuming that this was a css/styling bug and I just needed to tweak my print style sheet to get it to work, except the issue does not exist in our development region, no matter what I did I could not reproduce it.  So my next guess was that there was a discrepency between the code on the two sites; so I totally wiped out our dev site, refreshed it with the exact same files that are in production, and it still works in dev but not on the production site.  I used beyond compare to do a full binary compare between the folders containing the two sites and it came back as a perfect match.

As a final test I saved the HTML source output from both dev and production and did a compare, they were exactly the same except for image paths and a few ASP.Net generated paths (which change every time the page loads and is expected).

So the question is: whats going on and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your dev and production sites live on the same instance of IIS with identical configurations, they are not the same.

Since you've excluded the site itself, I'd move lower down the ladder and look at the config of each site, and so on.